# phpMyAdmin: "Choose Field to display" doesn't show off

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to display more columns in phpmyadmin's drop-down boxes when inserting records in related tables (by foreign key constraints).

I created two tables:

- tab1 with columns id (int), name (char).
- tab2 with columns id (int), idTab1 (int, FK).

tab2.idTab1 is related to tab1.id.

The problem is when visualizing the drop-down box in insert tab it displays only the available tab1.id records like 1 -, 2 -, ...

I'd like to know how to show tab1.name next each tab1.id record in drop-down box.
Someone told me to use "Choose Field to display", but this option doesn't show.

Answer (score 3):

It's really the "Choose **column** to display" (phpMyAdmin 4+, for sure) that you want. It can be found by two ways:

1. "Designer" page (main menu). The option it's in one of the top icons;
2. "Relation View" page, that can be accessed by the "Structure" page (main menu). The link to the relation view is right below from the fields of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with phpmyadmin's designer. After you created the Foreign key relation in the visual designer you can choose which column to display when inserting values into the table with the foreign key (Icon "Choose column to display").

[Here is a nice little tutorial](http://www.ubuntu-center.de/1399/der-designer-von-phpmyadmin/) which also contains the solution to your problem.

Comment: We can follow by the images, but, deutsch tutorial??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice as german is my native language. This could help if the option is not available: [How to enable displaying choose column to display in phpmyadmin](http://serverfault.com/questions/365997/how-to-enable-displaying-choose-column-to-display-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the [`ForeignKeyMaxLimit`](http://imxserver/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html#cfg_ForeignKeyMaxLimit) to `0` to always display the popup for foreign key selection. This setting can be changed on a per-session-basis directly within phpMyAdmin (*Homepage -> More settings -> Main frame [Tab] -> Edit mode [Tab] -> Foreign key limit*) or in the config files of your installation.

Comment: That's not provided as feature in phpMyAdmin – the alternative is the popup, where every foreign key is listed with some more columns…

Comment: The popup only lists the foreign id key and value, no other fields. It's not any more usesful that the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

May you can try `Show/Hide table list`

Go to phpmyadmin -> Designer -> `Left Bar(Show/Hide table list)` -> So you can check/uncheck table that you want to display